# 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, authentication

I am trying perform an auto login by redirecting the user to an external website supplying the authentication information in the header. Tested that it's working in postman. But I am getting a 'Response' object has no attribute 'get' in django when I click on a button which perform this request. I think I am doing this wrongly. What would be the best way to redirect to an external web provided I have the authorization information? Ajax?

```
    if req.method == 'POST':
        url = "https://server.to.reach"

        headers = {
            'Authorization': "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=",
            'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
            'Postman-Token': "546de0c9-a4fc-4c0b-8b99-bfbadc9ee7e4",
            'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }

        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers)

        print(response.text)
        return response
```

Comment: You need to explain in more detail what you are trying to do. What does "redirect to an external web" mean? What are you intending to happen?

Comment: A Django `HttpResponse` and a `response` from `python-requests` are two different classes. You can't return that response from a Django view.

Comment: I am trying to redirect to an external website and doing an auto login. I am able to see that I login to the website using postman by sending a post request with the headers shown above. But, not able to implement it in django. Within Django, I wanted to use a button to trigger a post request which would then display the response from django view. Is there a way to do that?